# Kubernetes unknown field "volumeMounts"

Tags: kubernetes, volume

I am trying to create MySQL Database Deployment but I am getting the below error.

Could you please check and help me to fix this issue?

**Error Message:**
C:\Users\Azvmadmin15.docker\YAML>kubectl apply -f mysqlpvc.yaml
service/mysql-srv created

Error from server (BadRequest):

### error when creating "mysqlpvc.yaml": StatefulSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a StatefulSet: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.ports",** unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumeMounts"
**

C:\Users\Azvmadmin15.docker\YAML>kubectl get all
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1               443/TCP    78m
service/mysql-srv    ClusterIP   10.108.13.118           3306/TCP   17m

C:\Users\Azvmadmin15.docker\YAML>kubectl get pv
NAME              CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                    STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
mysql-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/mysql-pv-claim   manual                  64m

C:\Users\Azvmadmin15.docker\YAML>kubectl get pvc
NAME             STATUS   VOLUME            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mysql-pv-claim   Bound    mysql-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            manual         67m

C:\Users\Azvmadmin15.docker\YAML>kubectl get all
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1               443/TCP    78m
service/mysql-srv    ClusterIP   10.108.13.118           3306/TCP   17m

---

```html
YAML file: 

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql-ss
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "mysql-pod"
  serviceName: "mysql"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "mysql-pod"
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: tiger1234
      ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
        name: mysql
      volumeMounts:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/mysql

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-srv
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: "mysql"
```

Comment: volumeMounts should be inside container scope. ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#aws-ebs-configuration-example

Answer (score 2):

You have indentation issues with `ports` and `volumeMounts`, below YAML should work

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql-ss
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "mysql-pod"
  serviceName: "mysql"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "mysql-pod"
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: tiger1234
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-srv
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: "mysql"
```

See the examples in docs for [volumeMounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/#configure-a-volume-for-a-pod) and [ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#using-pods)